# AngularJS BootstrapTypeahead not respecting placeholder text

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the official Bootstrap implementation from the Angular UI team so it's not angular-strap but angular-bootstrap. I have a typeahead that is working fine but it's not respecting the placeholder text. The reason is because I have a space in my result text.

Here's an example...

```
<input type="text" id="clientSelected" ng-model="clientSelected" typeahead="client as (client.firstName + ' ' + client.lastName) for client in clients | filter:$viewValue" placeholder="Just start typing...">
```

The client names are listed as: John Doe, Jane Doe, etc.. so nothing out of the ordinary there. Here is the controller part responsible for populating clients.

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
  // Result has come back from the server
  $scope.clients = result;

  // Doesn't fix the problem
  $scope.clientSelected = '';

  // Hack to fix typeahead
  angular.element('#clientSelected').val('');
});
```

So, with this implementation my input always has a `" "` so the placeholder isn't shown and the initial value of `ng-model="clientSelected"` is a `" "`. The space in the typeahead between `(client.firstName + ' ' + client.lastName)` is the reason.

Having a jQuery background, I'm immediately tempted to use the hack code above to force it to zero characters. Obviously, this isn't right and I'm missing something fundamental.

So, how can I tell the `input` to be zero characters or just fix the problem entirely?

Comment: this is actually something that should be fixed in the typeahead directive. I saw it once but forgotten to address. Could you open an issue in https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap ?

Comment: Absolutely, I will put the post here over there.